# ASP.NET Core Double validation dots doesnt work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my validation, my input is double, but when I type for example "3.14", I got error message: "The value '3.14' is not valid for Fueling", if I do it with commas (,) its working. I want to use both dots and commas for input. What should I do?
My globalization is HU-hu (hungary, basic separator is commas).

**EDIT - Code**

```
[Display(Name = "Tankolás")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0} l", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    [FuelValidation]
    public double? Fueling { get; set; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Fueling" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Fueling" class="form-control" placeholder="Tankolás" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Fueling" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Validation:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var record = (RoadRecord)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        if (value != null)
        {
           value = double.Parse(value.ToString(), new CultureInfo("hu-HU"));
            if (!((double)value <= 0))
            {
                
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                return new ValidationResult("Legyen nagyobb mint 0");
            }
            
        }
        else
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to provide some code for us to help better

Comment: I edited the post, added some code

Comment: if you want to have both then you need to try parsing one by one both , you can use tryparse with your culture first and if it fails then you tryparse with invariant culture. eventually you will get your double value.

Comment: And where should I do that? In the validation class? or in model? etc.

Comment: validation class and validation should be done in backend not in frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can consider using a piece of JavaScript code to assist with validation. If you just use custom Validation, you will get null when you pass 3.14, so you can't proceed with validation.

Use JS in the view to judge the passed parameters, if it is 3.14, change it to 3,14 for passing will solve this problem.

Below is my test code,you can refer to it:

```
<form asp-action="Index">
    <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Fueling" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input id="Fueling" asp-for="Fueling" class="form-control" placeholder="Tankolás" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Fueling" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button onclick="Test()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>

</form>
<script>
    function Test()
    {
        var param = $("#Fueling").val();
        if (param.indexOf(".") != -1) 
        {
            param = param.replace(".",",");
        }
        $("#Fueling").val(param);
    }
</script>
```

Test Result:

When I enter 3,14:

[image]
[image]

When I enter 3.14:

[image]

After processing：

[image]
[image]